# Win7: change monitor identities

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to change the identities of my monitors. I have 6 monitors connected, and the identities are [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXmSG.jpg).  I want to change them so they are [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvpb9.jpg). I want all the monitors to stay in the same place, I just want to change the identity numbers, so that the monitor currently identified as 4 changes to be identified as 2.

[There are](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/736116-windows-display-properties-identify-numbers-are)  quite [a few](https://www.sevenforums.com/graphic-cards/404889-monitor-identity-issue.html)  things [on Google](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2357190/changing-windows-monitor-identities.html) for [what I](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/657768-HowTo-Switch-monitor-1-Monitor-2-Identity) want [to do](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f9e088f5-5449-4ae6-97a3-92a972d3e1c6/multiple-monitor-change-number?forum=w7itproui).  They all say basically one of 2 things:

1. use an external utility
2. delete some registry keys, disconnect all monitors, reboot, then reconnect them in the order you want them identified.

It's a corporate laptop, so external utilities are restricted.  As for option 2, I've deleted all the keys the posts suggest:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivity
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\DISPLAY
```

And rebooted, and reconnected the monitors one by one in the order I want.  It works until I connect the 3rd external monitor (currently #2, I want it to be #4). At that point, that monitor takes over #2 and the identities all revert back to the configuration I currently have.

Is there any way to force the monitors to be identified the way I want without having to physically take them down and move them around?

Perhaps worth noting: I am connected to a docking station that has 3 display connectors (VGA, DVI, DP). I have 3 monitors hooked up to it with VGA, DP, and USB. If I try to plug in a 4th monitor to the DVI slot while the 3 are connected, it doesn't get detected.  The other 2 monitors are connected through an external USB docking station, which has an HDMI port and a DVI port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in the future, I figured out why my registry edits weren't working.

The problem had to do with where my monitors were connected.  They were as follows (all identities are the actual ones, not the desired ones):

1. laptop
2. VGA directly into docking station
3. Display Port directly into docking station
4. DVI through a USB dongle, into docking station
5. DVI into daisy-chained docking station, connected to main docking station by USB
6. HDMI into daisy-chained docking station, connected to main docking station by USB

As you can see, the more links there were between the monitor and my laptop, the higher the number.  This is why when I connected the first 2 monitors (#4 and #6), everything was fine, because the USB dongle was closer to the laptop than the external docking station.  But once I tried to connect #2 directly into the main docking station, #2 became the nearest monitor, so it took over identity #2.

I was able to resolve the problem by swapping the connections for monitors #3 and #6, and monitors #2 and #4.  Then, when I deleted the registry keys and reconnected the monitors one-by-one, They correctly identified themselves in the order they were connected.

[And everything is right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SCtd.jpg)